# Linq tolist() count returns different value from translated sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, count

I have a situation where the translated sql direct form Visual Studio is returning a different number of records from the Linq. I am expecting 4 items but in the count() of the resulting list I only have 1. This is the case despite creating more records - it always returns 1.

```
db.DCLVUnknowns.Where(x => x.DCLVUnknownId == Report.DCLid).ToList();

SELECT 
[Extent1].[DCLVUnknownId] AS [DCLVUnknownId], 
[Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
[Extent1].[Height] AS [Height], 
[Extent1].[Weight] AS [Weight],
[Extent1].[Age] AS [Age],
[Extent1].[Race] AS [Race],
[Extent1].[DCLid] AS [DCLid] 
FROM [dbo].[DCLVUnknown] AS [Extent1]
```

Strange thing is I have the same linq expression running fine for other entities and there is no problem. It is consistently happening at the same spot every time.

[image]

Comment: Is that LINQ expression supposed to be the same as that SQL? Because the SQL is missing a WHERE related to `DCLVUnknownId == Report.DCLid`, or perhaps that is filtered in the client?

Comment: Not sure, but I think it's a VS19 bug. I've seen this before, where the ServerExplorer does not commit changes properly to database. Try restarting VS19.

Comment: If you have a list that both claims to have a Count of 1, and then the results view shows 4, then I'd say this is a debugger issue. Have you tried with `Debug.WriteLine(whatever.Count);` and see what it says?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen uh good point - why would linq be generating that? In either case all the current data in the table would be returned by that query with the where clause added

Comment: You're inspecting `db.DCLVUnknowns` in that screenshot. Like, the whole table. So if you got that statement by copying the value you're seeing there then you didn't get any `where` clause.

Comment: You can see from your snapshot that the `Local` storage is out of sync with the database. Also, you are hovering on the Set property which would return all items if enumerated (as seen in the snapshot). If you assign the list to a variable (`var list = db.DCLVUnknowns.Where(x => x.DCLVUnknownId == Report.DCLid).ToList();`) and then inspect the variable in the debugger, how many items do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.DCLVUnknowns
```

Is a query of the entire table, not the query for what you want.

If you want to inspect the IQueryable of the full query, try:

```
var results = db.DCLVUnknowns.Where(x => x.DCLVUnknownId == Report.DCLid);
var theResultSet = results.ToList();
```

Here `results` should translate as roughly:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[DCLVUnknownId] AS [DCLVUnknownId], 
[Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
[Extent1].[Height] AS [Height], 
[Extent1].[Weight] AS [Weight],
[Extent1].[Age] AS [Age],
[Extent1].[Race] AS [Race],
[Extent1].[DCLid] AS [DCLid] 
FROM [dbo].[DCLVUnknown] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[DCLVUnknownId] = DCLid
```

Assuming DCLVUnknownId is a PK/ Identity, you should see one result in `theResultSet`.